# Read .txt file from AWS S3 storage in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, amazon-s3, react-hooks

I am trying to read text file from s3 storage in ReactJS. I have the s3 bucket link of the text file. However, I am not able to read the text file from the link. I have googled a lot about this, but everywhere people are reading the file locally and not from a link.

The link of the file looks like this:

```
https://bucketnmame.s3.amazonaws.com/folder1/folder2/file.txt
```

This link is being stored in database with NodeJS as backend. Would be great if someone helps me...

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
fetch('https://bucketnmame.s3.amazonaws.com/folder1/folder2/file.txt')
    .then ((response) => response.text())
    .then (data => {
      console.log(data)
    });
```

Comment: This is giving CORS error

Comment: CORS error indicates your origin (site/domain) is not allowed to make `GET` requests to the bucket. The S3 bucket owner should change the CORS config to allow `https://yourdomain.com` or `*` or potentially `http://localhost:3000` if you are running from the default create-react-app development server.

Comment: Here is a test S3 file for you to try `https://sf-tar-poc.s3.amazonaws.com/test.txt`. I have the following CORS config on the bucket `[{"AllowedHeaders": ["*"],"AllowedMethods": ["GET"], "AllowedOrigins": ["*"],"ExposeHeaders": ["ETag"],"MaxAgeSeconds": 3000}]`. Note this bucket will only exist for another week or so.

Comment: Can you please give me a link where I can read this formatting and apply it?

Comment: This link has instructions for configuring CORS using the AWS Console, SDK, or API - [Configuring cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enabling-cors-examples.html)

Comment: Also, please mark the answer as correct if this has worked for you (So I gain internet points!)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has worked for me totally...